# How to couple authentication of two Rails apps

Tags: rest, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, single-page-application

My question is a little more complex, then the title supposes.

I've got two Rails4 apps. Both access the same mongodb via mongoid. Both use devise 3.0.0 for authentication, both have the same user model which is devise enabled and uses the same collection.

The first app delivers only an api at the domain:

```
api.myapp.com
```

The second app delivers the related website from

```
myapp.com
```

In addition I deliver a JS singlepage application from:

```
app.myapp.com
```

The latter one can access the API without problems, and uses a self made token authentication patch on top of devise, so that the token can be transferred as a HTTP header.

Both Rails apps have the same content in:

```
config/initializers/devise.rb
config/initializers/secret_token
config/initializers/session_store
```

The latter one looks like:

```
Web::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', domain: :all
```

Here's what I do now in my Backbone based single page application:

1. I log into the app
2. The app gets an auth_token from the API
3. The app stores the token
4. The single page application requests several additional resources using the token
5. The response headers set a cookie

Since the cookie is set, I'd expext to be logged in in my Rails website under myapp.com as well. Bummer! I am not.

So to falsify an API problem I do the following:

1. I start a REST Client in Chrome
2. I log into the API using this client and get a token
3. I request one additional resource using the client and the token
4. The response header sets a cookie
5. Now I go into my Rails website and ... voila I am logged in

I'm confused about that behaviour. The API seems to deliver correct cookies when a resource is requested and a user is logged in. Else I would not be logged in my website after makeing use of the REST client.

But if my single page app does exactly the same as the REST client, and receives response headers that set cookies as well, I am not logged in my website.

Does anybody have a hint?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 1):

You can use Central Authentication server [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service) then in each application you can use omniauth gem to sign in exactly like how you use facebook or twitter login in both of your applications.

This will eliminate the headache of handling the cookies and ticket yourself.

You can use [CASINO](http://casino.rbcas.com/) for that it's easy to install and use, and you can use [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) with [omniauth-cas](https://github.com/dlindahl/omniauth-cas)

And you can integrate it the same way you integrate any omniauth gem with devise.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set a specific scope on your cookie by adding a domain parameter that doesn't include the fully qualified domain name.

Instead of the cookie being under "api.myapp.com" or "www.myapp.com" it needs to be shared by being referenced as "myapp.com"

Example :

```
cookies[cookie_name] = {:value =>token, :domain => 'myapp.com'}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: That's a good hint. But the session_store config mentioned above already set's the domain to '.myapp.com' which should match all subdomains. Since all three apps are served from subdomains from within the domain, it should work. Meanwhile I handcrafted xhr requests manually, logged in a user at the api, requested a resource, got a cookie for .myapp.com but am not logged in at the web app. Going out of options here.